# Disable Date Grouping in Excel 2016 Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, grouping, excel-2016

I have tried googling extensively, but was unable to find an answer on how to **disable date grouping in Excel Pivot tables**. There are a number of good pages offering solutions. For example, https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2017/01/19/how-to-prevent-grouped-dates-in-excel and https://www.pivot-table.com/2019/05/08/stop-pivot-table-date-grouping suggest

```
 File --> Options --> Data --> Data Options --> Disable automatic grouping of Date/Time columns in PivotTables
```

However, the problem is that in my Excel (Professional Plus 2016), there is no `Data` entry under `Options`. So another site https://www.excelcampus.com/pivot-tables/grouping-dates-pivot-table-versus-grouping-dates-source-data correctly point out that the `Data` entry may in a different location:

```
 File --> Options --> Advanced --> Data --> Disable automatic grouping of Date/Time columns in PivotTables
```

---

I can indeed find `File --> Options --> Advanced --> Data`, but there is still no option to disable date grouping (see below screenshot). **Anybody have any advice on this?**

*Side note, I've also tried disabling `File --> Options --> Advanced --> Group dates in AutoFilter menu`, but it had no effect.*

[image]

Comment: Look at [Stop Pivot Table Grouping](https://www.pivot-table.com/2019/05/08/stop-pivot-table-date-grouping/)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I even listed this site in my post. It did not help.

Comment: Not even the registry hack?

Comment: Do you mean "Excel 2016 Registry Tweak ... To do that, follow the instructions in this article by Microsoft’s Excel team"? The link is down, unfortunately.

Comment: Try `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\DateAutoGroupingDisabled` and set DWord Value:=1